# Validation for Oracle Apex Editable Interactive Grid before edits are saved to the database

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to validate one column in the oracle apex editable Interactive Grid. I added a page validation with pl/sql code and used apex_error.add_error() to display the error message both in field and notification. I encountered problem when I edited multiple rows and more than one row did not pass validation.

Since in Editable Interactive Grid, I have so many rows displayed. I want to know how to refer to the specific field (specific columns and rows) to display the error message. I tried to create a hidden column and used it as the field to display the error message. But when I multiple rows did not pass validation, only the latest error message is displayed because the others were overwritten. Any ideas on how I can fix this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that using the declarative way in APEX you can achieve this. I have already answered your other question about this: [Display error message inline with field in Oracle Apex interactive grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100939/display-error-message-inline-with-field-in-oracle-apex-interactive-grid)