# Display error message inline with field in Oracle Apex interactive grid

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I tried to add error message to an interactive grid after validation fails. I followed the documentation for apex_error.add_error procedure for tabular forms, but I could not get the error message to display inline with field in the interactive grid.

I tried the region id with the number format and varchar format, and column alias name with the column name in the db and name that is displayed on the browser. I am also thinking to display the message only in notification and add javascript to copy the notification somewhere, but I am not very sure how to do that. The html on the page looks like this:

```
<li class="a-Notification-item htmldbStdErr"> ::before "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "LEDGER1_NAME": invalid identifier for SEC_OBJ_CODE= erwq"
</li>

 APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR( p_message          => apex_json.get_varchar2('Message')||' for SEC_OBJ_CODE= ' ||:SEC_OBJ_CODE,
    p_display_location =>  apex_error.c_inline_with_field_and_notif,
    p_region_id   => '3104734890213506',
    p_column_alias => 'Sec Obj Val Sql',
    p_row_num  => :ROWID);
```

The error I got is:

> Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX -
>   Error processing validation. - Contact your application administrator.

Comment: Not sure what the error here is about, but you could try entering debug mode and view the debug then. It shows a lot more information
Also, I usually try all javascript code in the console, so you know what its actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

To create a validation on a column of the interactive grid and display an error message associated with the column, do as follows:

1. On page designer mode, search for you interactive grid region, expand the columns section and right click the column that you want to be validated and click create validation:

[image]

2. Now you can build your validation using **Type** under "**Validation**" section;
3. Under "**Error**" section, you can write your error message, set "*display location*" to "**Inline with field**" or "**Inline with field and in notification**" and "*associated column*" with the column you are validating (this will be filled already).