# Highlight Column in Custom Validation in Interactive Grid Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an IG where I am doing custom validation via PL/SQL. Everything is working except that the respective column in not getting highlighted in IG.
Following is the APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR signature I have used.

```
apex_error.add_error (
    p_message          => 'Invalid Customer ID!',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_with_field_and_notif,
    p_region_id        => l_region_id,
    p_column_alias     => 'CUSTOMER_ID',
    p_row_num          => 1);
```

`p_region_id` is calculated inside code
`p_column_alias` is the column name in IG

I am not sure how to get `p_row_num` in code, so just to test code, I have used 1 (there is only one row in IG that I am validating)

Any idea how can I highlight IG column whenever error occur? And how to get `p_row_num` ?

Answer (score 0):

[For the rownum u could use :APEX$ROW_NUM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#CHDHIHID), but this only works in tabular forms, which is a legacy APEX component. I am having the same issue and am reverting to using [the validations in the APEX builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100939/display-error-message-inline-with-field-in-oracle-apex-interactive-grid).